# Bash: Best Practices for Moving a File from Clipboard?

Tags: linux, bash, clipboard

I'm trying to move a file from the clipboard using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the file path from the clipboard
file=$(xclip -selection clipboard -o)

# Move the file
mv "$file" "/home/sarah/Music/Indexing/Indexing Temp/"
```

However, `mv` does not support `file://` syntax. Should I just clip the file string using `tr` first, or is there another recommended solution to this issue?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which `xclip` version on which sstem outputs file URL? I seem to get standard paths on few installs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter substitution with `#`. See `man bash`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get the file path from the clipboard
file=$(xclip -selection clipboard -o)

# Remove 'file://' header
file="${file#file://}"

# Move the file
mv "$file" "/home/sarah/Music/Indexing/Indexing Temp/"
```